# Functional Tests in Redmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, redmine

I got some problems when writing the functional tests for my Redmine plugin.
Well, I created a plugin in Redmine named Polls, in controller I defined two function named *index* and *vote* as bellow:

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController
  unloadable
  before_filter :find_project, :authorize, :only => :index
  def index
    @polls = Poll.all
  end

  def vote
    poll = Poll.find(params[:id])
    poll.vote(params[:answer])
    if poll.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Vote saved.'
    end
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
  private

  def find_project
    # @project variable must be set before calling the authorize filter
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end
end
```

The *index* function will list all data in Polls table (the data get from sample data in *polls.yml* file and fetch to table Polls) and display inside each project was created.
Here is my sample data in *polls.yml* file:

```
poll_001:
    id: 1
    question: Can you see this poll?
    is_yes: 2
    is_no: 0
poll_002:
    id: 2
    question: And can you see this other poll?
    is_yes: 1
    is_no: 0
```

And the vote function will increment for each answer by one, the answer get from user. I have been defined the *vote* function in my model and invoked it at here.
Block code of the *vote* function in Poll model:

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base

    def vote(answer)
        increment(answer == 'yes' ? :is_yes : :is_no)
    end
end
```

For now, I writing two test cases in functional tests:

```
require File.expand_path('../../test_helper', __FILE__)
class PollsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    fixtures :projects, :users, :roles, :members, :polls
    def setup
        @project = Project.find(1)
        User.current = User.find(2)
        @request.session[:user_id] = 2
        @poll = Poll.all
    end

    test "index" do
        Role.find(1).add_permission! :view_polls
        get :index, :project_id => @project.id
        assert_response :success
        assert_template 'index'
    end

    test "vote" do
        post :vote, {:id => 1, :answer => 'no'}
        assert_equal 'Vote saved.', expect(flash[:notice])
        assert_response :success
        assert_template 'index'
    end
end
```

I get an error while run test index:

```
# Running:
F
Finished in 1.051095s, 0.9514 runs/s, 0.9514 assertions/s.
  1) Failure:
PollsControllerTest#test_index [polls_controller_test.rb:14]:
Expected response to be a <success>, but was <403>
1 runs, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

and while run test vote:

```
# Running:

E

Finished in 0.288799s, 3.4626 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
PollsControllerTest#test_vote:
NoMethodError: undefined method `expect' for #<PollsControllerTest:0x7c71c60>


1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a suspicious code in `PollsControllerTest`:

```
assert_equal 'Vote saved.', expect(flash[:notice])
```

you probably mean:

```
assert_equal 'Vote saved.', flash[:notice]
```

Comment: Thank you, dimakura . It worked, but I get other error on this test: Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>

Comment: It should exactly be 302. You redirect `redirect_to :action => 'index'` after voting!

Comment: What should I do to get away this message, and how to I can get value of is_yes or is_no attribute. Sincerely!

Comment: Use `assert_response :redirect` instead of `assert_response :success`

Comment: Thank you so much, dimakura. And how to get value of an attribute after voting!

Comment: `Poll.find(1)` and it contains all attributes you need.

Comment: Btw, using hard-coded ids in test is not the best practice

Comment: What should I do it better, and are you on Skype?

Comment: Your full name is Dimitri Kurashvili, you have received a request from @khailv94(Khai Le) ?